# How to get client_id and client_secret for Azure Digital Twin Swagger?

Tags: azure-digital-twins

It is not clear from documentation of Azure Digital Twin Swagger, how to get Client ID and Client Secret. From the url link, figured it client_id as Application ID, however not able to get how to set  client_secret:?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 i can't get the swagger to work either - would be neat though. i've done all my explorations through writing code and using postman.

The tutorials are very good. There is an excellent walk-through on how to register an app in AAD and get the needed clientId and clientSecret bits. It's for postman, but start to finish it works very well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/security-authenticating-apis

Comment: Thanks. I have noted the same. Now, I will try. Hope GA document will be better, how to use Swagger.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. We've been steadily improving the quality of our documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it's not currently possible to authenticate to Digital Twins directly from Swagger, however, we did want to provide the Swagger sample as a "sneak peak." But, the docs do need updating as it's not clear that "try it out" is not functional. Thank you for your input. As mentioned above postman is an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the feedback. I'm one of the Content Developers (documentation team). The Azure Digital Twins platform and documentation are being improved continuously.

During Public Preview, certain functionalities are not fully available (largely due to significant permanent improvements that are being made). These are specified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/digital-twins/concepts-service-limits.

Additionally, the Postman document has been improved with additional information: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/digital-twins/how-to-configure-postman.

To find your Azure Active Directory identifiers, check out the Quickstart document in particular. It walks through most of the core functionalities: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/digital-twins/quickstart-view-occupancy-dotnet!